# Thin white blank area added to right side of page on Android Chrome

Tags: php, html, css, mobile

Page: https://merkd.com/new.php

The area boxed in red is the trouble area. On my desktop browser no matter how small I reduce the size of the window it will not allow me to scroll right and view this blank space, which leads me to believe its a mobile-only issue.

Additionally, on my device, when you load the page initially the page zooms so that you do not notice it unless you scroll over or zoom out.

I tried using Chrome Remote Debugging but could not get it to show me what element that white space belongs to.

Any ideas what may be causing it? I realize it could be quite a few things, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking a common issue or a silly mistake on my end.

Mobile View:

[image]

Comment: Helpful hint: You can debug it inside of Chrome if you turn on Emulation (Dev Tools > Emulation) and select a mobile phone layout.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that your `title-area` has margins on the `left/right` that cause it to overflow past the container it resides it, pushing out the edges.

So in short..

```
<div class="title-area" style="/* margin: 4em 1em -2.5em 1em; */">
```

Needs to become

```
<div class="title-area" style="margin:4 em 0 -2.5em;">
```

Comment: One of the easiest ways to resolve this is to inspect the <body> and start deleting `parent elements` until the issue goes away. Then drill into the child elements (after refreshing the page) and see which element it is.

Comment: Thank you, it seems so obvious now but I would have spent at least another hour racking my brain over it. I really appreciate the extra set of eyes!